# Password validation in UITextField in iOS 10 --> Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, validation, passwords

I'm having 1 UITextfield for password in my iPhone application.

I want to validate this textfield with the following validation.

Must be at least 6 characters

Must contain at least one english letter, one digit and Remaining all

special characters are make as optional (ie not mandetory)

how can I restrict the UITextField with above requirements. please anyone help me out to do this..

Comment: You can find answer of this question by yourself. don't ask this type of questions. there are already too much answers like this

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to validate your password:

```
-(BOOL) isPasswordValid:(NSString *)password {
    NSCharacterSet *upperCaseChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];
    NSCharacterSet *lowerCaseChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];
    //NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

    if ( [password length]<7 )
        return NO;  //too short
    NSRange range;
    range = [password rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
    if ( !range.length )
        return NO;  // no letter
    range = [password rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
    if ( !range.length )
        return NO;  // no number;
    range = [password rangeOfCharacterFromSet:upperCaseChars];
    if ( !range.length )
        return NO;  // no uppercase letter;
    range = [password rangeOfCharacterFromSet:lowerCaseChars];
    if ( !range.length )
        return NO;  // no lowerCase Chars;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hey Sivaram, Glad it worked for you. Please give an up-vote and click the tickmark as your issue is resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Below is what I use using RegEx

```
NSString *passwordRegex = @"^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$!&]).*$";
NSPredicate *passwordTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex];


if (![passwordTest evaluateWithObject:passwordTF.text]) {
    // Password must be at least 6 character, containing lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, digits, and special character (!@#$&)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
-(BOOL)isValidPasswordWithText:(UITextField *)textfield{

    NSString *regex1 = @"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*#?&]{6,}$";
    NSPredicate *test1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex1];
    return [test1 evaluateWithObject:textfield.text] ;
}
```

Comment: @Sivaram Yadav did you check ?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Vamshi Krishna's answer, I think it could be more simple.

The `decimalDigitCharacterSet` can match any digital characters. Since the OP's intention didn't mention the upper case issue, so the `letterCharacterSet` should be enough here.

FYI:

```c
BOOL ValidatePassword(NSString *candidate)
{
    if (candidate.length < 6) {
        return NO;
    }

    BOOL foundLetter = [candidate rangeOfCharacterFromSet:NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet].location != NSNotFound;
    BOOL foundDigit = [candidate rangeOfCharacterFromSet:NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet].location != NSNotFound;

    return foundLetter && foundDigit;
}
```